# PyFlink Sliding Window on a Datastream fails with AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

I have a running PyFlink Application implemented in with `apache-flink==1.16.0`. To deploy this app to AWS Kinesis Analytics i have to downgrade it to `apache-flink==1.15.2` as AWS does not support newer versions.

The problem is that i have no idea how to create a sliding window based on a datastream.

#### What works well in Version 1.16:

```py
input_stream = self.table_env.to_data_stream(flat_table)
result_stream = input_stream.key_by(get_key) \
    .window(CountSlidingWindowAssigner.of(self.window_size, self.window_slide)) \
    .apply(MyWindowFunction(),
           output_type=Types.TUPLE([Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.FLOAT(), Types.FLOAT(), Types.FLOAT()]))
```

#### However in Version 1.15

Here the code had to be slightly adjusted:

```py
input_stream = self.table_env.to_data_stream(flat_table)
result_stream = input_stream.key_by(get_key) \
    .window(CountSlidingWindowAssigner(self.window_size, self.window_slide)) \
    .apply(CTATThresholds(),
           result_type=Types.TUPLE([Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(),
                                    Types.STRING(), Types.FLOAT(), Types.FLOAT(), Types.FLOAT()]))
```

and the `.apply()` function throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'CountSlidingWindowAssigner' object has no attribute 'get_default_trigger'
```

I am looking forward to any advice or idea!

Comment: have you found any solution  @Michael Boesl?

Comment: Hello @SybghatallahMarwat ,sorry for my late reply! I was in contact with AWS Support regarding this topic and the outcome was that i had to rewrite my application in Scala. Honestly it was not as hard as it might sound and i faced almost no problems to deploy a flink app based on Scala to AWS.